# Is there an algorithm for finding needed operations that given some input and result?

Tags: algorithm, math

Is there a way to get the operations needed to get from some input to a specific output?
For example, I have some input 1 and output 3. I also have a couple of operations, `F(x)=x+1` and `G(x)=x-1`. How would I create a program that would find that the solution of `F(F(x))`

Another example, with operations of `F(x)=-x` and `G(x)=-2x`. With an input of 1 and an output of 2. The solution requires `F(x)` to be used but `F(x)` increases the difference between the input and output.

Note: Operations may not be linear and may include some variable constant.

Comment: If you don't know anything about the functions or even if it's possible you can use breadth-first recursion to explore the problem space, but it might never complete. Think of it like a graph: each edge is the application of a function and each node is a unique number.  You are looking for a path from one node to another. You only need to consider nodes you haven't already visited to find the shortest path.

Comment: "some variable constant": mh, do you mean a fixed number that changes ?

Comment: Yes, say for example I have a function `F(x)=ax` where a can be set to any number within a given range @YvesDaoust

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a **shortest path in an implicit infinite graph**. You have two vertices, which you called the "input" and "output". You want to find a path from the former to the latter. The edges of the graph are given by the functions F and G.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is uncomputable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your description of the problem is pretty lacunary. Anyway, I guess that it can be solved by brute force:

- maintain a set of values "reached" so far, initially empty, and a set of "new" values, initially containing the starting value, `{1}`.
- apply `F` to the "new" set, here giving `{2}`
- apply `G` to the "new" set, here giving `{0}`
- take the union of the images, minus the "reached" set to get a new "new" set, (giving `{0,2}`) and add the images to the "reached" set (giving `{0,1,2}`).

At the next iteration, you will get "new" `{-1,3}` and "reached" `{-1,0,1,2,3}`. And so on. Obviously, you stop when you reach the target value.

To obtain the path that led to the final value, you can tag every element with a "parent", i.e. another element that led to it by `F` or `G` (and a flag telling which). E.g., `2 = F(1)`.

---

For the second example,

```
{1}, {}
{-2,-1}, {-2,-1,1}
{4}, {-2,-1,1,2,4}
{-4,-8}, {-8,-2,-1,1,2,4}
{8}, {-8,-2,-1,1,2,4,8}
...
```